# Find the characterisitc function for a standardised binomial random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Find the characteristic function of $Y$.

I know the formula for the characteristic function. This is a question from a past exam that doesn't provide answers and I'm unsure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if formatting isn't correct!

Answer (score 0):

We assume you know $\phi_X(t)=E(e^{itX})=\sum_1^n \binom{n}{k} e^{itk} p^k(q)^{n-k}=\sum \binom{n}{k} (e^{it}p)^k (q)^{n-k}=(pe^{it}+(q))^n$.

Now can you work out a way to get $E(e^{itX})$ from $E(e^{itY})$?

More so can you factor: $$E(e^{itY})$$ After that we are done.

Well we know $$E(e^{itY})=E(e^{it\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{npq}}})=E(e^{it\frac{X}{\sqrt{npq}}}e^{-it\frac{np}{\sqrt{npq}}})=\phi_X \left(\frac t{\sqrt{npq}}\right)e^{-it\frac{np}{\sqrt{npq}}}$$

And ${\sqrt{npq}}$ is a constant.

How about now?

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not quite sure where to go from there

Comment: Ok thank you yes I'm pretty sure I've figured it out from there. The next part of the question says to show that it converges to $e^{(-t^2/2)}$. How would I do this?

Comment: Well since Y is essentially the Normal approximation to the Binomial distribution, I assume it wants $n \to \infty$. See what happens when n is large?

Comment: I know I'm not doing this right but once I have the characteristic function of Y, if I let n approach infinity I get the wrong answer. Sorry I'm really struggling

Comment: It then asks to find the limiting distribution of Y

Comment: Well we can solve the last question here: https://surfstat.anu.edu.au/surfstat-home/3-2-8.html. Have a read of that see if it helps!

Comment: Are you able to walk me through the answer? I'm just not sure what steps to follow

Comment: Sure lets try! But first what is the formula for your characteristic function?

Comment: I think this is right? 
$(pe^{\frac{itq}{\sqrt{npq}}}+qe^{\frac{-itp}{\sqrt{npq}}})^n$

Comment: Ah! Okay so we are getting the wrong characteristic function still. Think about $\phi_{aX+b}(t)$. I recommend you try to get the characteristic function again and post another question with all the parts and what you tried exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In general $$\phi_{aX+b}(t)=\mathbb Ee^{it(aX+b)}=\mathbb Ee^{itb}e^{iatX}=e^{itb}\mathbb Ee^{iatX}=e^{itb}\phi_X(at)$$